# What is the UID in the logger library in ruby

Tags: ruby, logging

I read an article on how to login ruby [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/rubyists-love-logging/)

```
class MyLog
  def self.log
    if @logger.nil?
      @logger = Logger.new STDOUT
      @logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
      @logger.datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S '
    end
    @logger
  end
end
```

Here are some lines from the log that was created when I used the code:

```
D, [2017-12-25 14:50:48 #39617] DEBUG -- : Module: ......
D, [2017-12-25 14:50:48 #39617] DEBUG -- : Module: ......
```

Any idea what is creating the value **39617** ? As far as I can tell, only the format of the date and time is defined. What is controlling the inclusion of this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [pid of ruby process](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format). You can check it with `Process.pid`